# Create a serialization anomaly with just 1 statement per transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i and a certain someone got trapped in a disagreement. my claim is that any set of transactions is always serializable as long as they only contain a single statement that reads xor writes. to create an unserializable set of transactions, you need at least 2 transactions and two shared resources, like this:
T1 reads x,
T2 reads y,
T1 writes y,
T2 writes x

i also claim that adding a single transaction that does only a single read can never make the set of all transactions non-serializable.
am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

"A single statement that reads xor writes" is somewhat unclear. Would that include a single `UPDATE` statement? Consider this case:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_data bigint);

CREATE TABLE b (b_data bigint);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (42);

INSERT INTO b VALUES (42);
```

Now run these two transactions (T1 and T2):

```
T1:
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE a SET a_data = (SELECT count(*) FROM b);

T2:
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE b SET b_data = (SELECT count(*) FROM a);
COMMIT;

T1:
COMMIT;
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions
DETAIL:  Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during commit attempt.
HINT:  The transaction might succeed if retried.
```

Both transactions contain only a single DML statement, but that statement reads and writes.  However, there are very few DML statements that do not read; a typical `UPDATE` and `DELETE` will both read and write.  So I guess you can continue arguing.  Where you are right is that you need both read and write dependencies *somewhere* to get a serialization error, see theorem 1 in [this paper](https://drkp.net/papers/ssi-vldb12.pdf).

However, your second claim is definitely wrong. A read-only transaction can break serializability. Look at example 1.3 in [this paper](https://www.cs.umb.edu/%7Eponeil/ROAnom.pdf).